# Writing to an Existing Excel File

Tags: java, jxl, jxls

```
 package jexcel.jxl.nimit;

    import java.awt.Label;  
    import java.io.File;  
    import java.io.IOException;

    import jxl.Cell;   
    import jxl.CellType;  
    import jxl.LabelCell;  
    import jxl.NumberCell;  
    import jxl.Sheet;  
    import jxl.Workbook;  
    import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;  
    import jxl.write.WritableCell;  
    import jxl.write.WritableSheet;  
    import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;  
    import jxl.write.WriteException;  
    import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;  

    public class ExcelJxl {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws BiffException 
     * @throws WriteException 
     * @throws RowsExceededException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ExcelJxl.WriteFile("D:\nimit.xls");
    }

    public static void WriteFile(String path) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException{

    Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(path));

    WritableWorkbook copy=Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\temp.xls"),wb);
    WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(1); 
    WritableCell cell = sheet.getWritableCell(0,0); 
    String S="nimit";
    if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) 
    { 
      LabelCell l = (LabelCell) cell; 
      l.setString(S); 
    }
    copy.write(); 
    copy.close();
    wb.close();

    }
   }
```

I have edited my program, and now it says that setString() **The method setString(String) is undefined for the type LabelCell** I read the Documentation, there is a method setString in the LabelCell type.

Comment: There is no definition of method 'write' in the Workbook Class . Watch this : http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html

Comment: Here are some codes : http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html

Comment: But this example has it. [Link](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html) for writing into an excel file.

Comment: You're calling a write() method with Workbook instance wk while the example is using WritableWorkbook instance ...

Comment: Perhaps you should read the document or web more carefully ...

Comment: You should probably have a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605923/modifying-existing-excel-using-jxl?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605923/modifying-existing-excel-using-jxl?rq=1)

Comment: Where is the method setString? which documentation you went through?        http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sourceforge/jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12/jxl-2.6.12-javadoc.jar!/jxl/LabelCell.html gothrought the above doc

Comment: Since you have edited your question , there is nothing I can answer now ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LabelCell is just an interface with only one method i.e `getString()` you can learn more about it [here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/LabelCell.html)

You should use `jxl.write.Label` instead.
What you should exactly do is as follows
You should import the following file

```
import jxl.write.Label
```

Then following is the code for adding a cell at desired location to an excel file

```
Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fileToEdit.getAbsolutePath()));
WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), existingWorkbook);
WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(sheetName);
WritableCell cell;
Label l = new Label(currentColumn, currentRow, value);
cell = (WritableCell) l;
sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);
 workbookCopy.write();
 workbookCopy.close();
 existingWorkbook.close();
```

`currentColumn` and `currentRow` define the index and value contains the String to be placed in that cell.

Hope it helps

Comment: Worked for me (Y)