# Update existing Excel file

Tags: java, android, class

I'm trying to update an existing Excel file. I used the code I saw here [Writing to an Existing Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338383/writing-to-an-existing-excel-file#) but I can't call the function from the main activity.

I tried to create a instance from the department.

It is my code of the class

```
public class ExceLJxL {

    public ExceLJxL(){

    }

    public static void WriteFile(String path) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {

        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(path));

        WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\temp.xls"), wb);
        WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(1);
        WritableCell cell;
        Label l = new Label(1, 1, "");
        cell = (WritableCell) l;
        sheet.addCell(cell);

        copy.write();
        copy.close();
        wb.close();

    }
}
```

And here I call the function

```
 ExceLJxL exceLJxL= new ExceLJxl();
 exceLJxL.WriteFile( "path");
```

But he doesn't know it

Comment: Where are you calling this function from?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "he doesn't know it"?  Are you getting a specific error message?  If so, please add the exact text of the error message to your question.

Comment: `new File("D:\temp.xls")` Are you trying to make a copy on your Windows PC? `D:` is a partition on a Windows PC and unknown by Android OS.

Comment: I read from the main activity:


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view)  {

                ExceLJxL exceLJxL=new ExceLJxl();

                exceLJxL.WriteFile( "path");
            }


        });

    }

Comment: It writes Cannot resolve symbol 'ExceLJxl'

Comment: @Maxima, Java is case-sensitive.  The name of the class is "ExceLJx**L**", not "ExceLJx**l**" (the final 'L' is upper-case in the class name, but you're using a lower-case 'l' after the `new` keyword).