# Get - not create - an excell writable workbook that have already written in java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have created a new excell workbook using

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);
```

Then I have writen it and closed. 
Now I want to get that workbook by file name to **write** - not read only- some new data to it. I found that I can get the workbook by

```
Workbook workbook     = Workbook.getWorkbook(file).
```

But it is read only. What I want is get - not create - a writable workbook that have already written.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605923/modifying-existing-excel-using-jxl

Comment: Oh! Thanx. 1000000 times Ankur! I missed it!

Comment: You are welcome, but I will prefer POI solution,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521274/edit-existing-excel-files-using-jxl-api-apache-poi