# Updating result in Excel using JXL API in Selenium WebDriver test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium . I am able to get the data from excel sheet using .jxl jar

but unable to update the result into same excel sheet. So kindly help me  with this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what specific problem are you facing. any exceptions?

Comment: There is a good example that you can try here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605923/modifying-existing-excel-using-jxl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"xls" is a format of Excel 2007 which consist of binary BIFF data in an Object Linking and Embedding(OLE) container . The xlsx is a later format which is comprised of XML files in a zip container.The Java Excel API only deals with the first format so it throws an exception when it doesn't encounter an OLE container.

So if you use .poi API, which is a better tool than .jxl API that handles excel in a better way you problem might be solved.