# Modify data in excel using jxl without creating copy

Tags: android, database, sqlite, jxl, sqlhelper

I'm trying to use an excel file as a database and the app constantly needs to read and modify the file. As explained in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605923/modifying-existing-excel-using-jxl), it is necessary to create a copy of original excel file and all the modification has to be done there. Is there anyway to modify the excel file without creating a copy because I'll be using the file name at another instance to read it.

Also, I'd like your opinion on which one would be efficient as a database for offline access? An android sqlite or excel file ?