# JExcel - Modify Multiple Cells Before Closing WritableWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, for-loop, jexcelapi

I am trying to put a title in cell (0,0) and then use a `for()` loop to add file paths into each following row. However, I am only able to add one line of code; after the title, no other cells in the Excel document are modified.

Here's where I create the file:

```
private void chooseSheetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        sheetNum = chooseSheet.getSelectedIndex() - 1;
        try {
            WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(newXls);
            workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();

            writeXls();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewScore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And here's where I try to write to it:

```
public void writeXls() throws Exception {
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(newXls);
    WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(newXls, wb);
    WritableSheet ws = copy.getSheet(sheetNum);
    WritableCell cell;

    // Body Part - Title
    Label lab = new Label(0,0,partName);
    cell = (WritableCell) lab;
    ws.addCell(cell);
    copy.write();
    // Image Info
    int i = 1;
    for (File file : imageArray(dir)) {
        Label label = new Label (0,i,"test" + i);
        cell = label;
        ws.addCell(cell);
        copy.write();
        i++;
    }
    copy.close();
}
```

Is there a way to make my `for()` loop work, or do I need to go about this a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you checked if imageArray(dir) returns any data?Also it looks a bit strange that you are adding cells to one object, but calling write and close on another one. Shouldn't it be calls to one object?

Comment: Hi Bogdan! Yes, there are five files stored in imageArray(dir). As for adding cells and calling WritableWorkbooks, I'm trying to base my code off of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605923/modifying-existing-excel-using-jxl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Initially I was confused wether you are trying to create a new workbook or edit an existing one. But it looks like you need a new one here.

It appears there were two issues in the code example. 
First one is that you retrieved just created excel file and copied its content into itself.

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(newXls);
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(newXls, wb);
```

Another thing that I noticed is that in order to save all the changes it is required to call write on the WritableWorkbook instance only once in the end.

I finished with such code.

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "D:/test_out.xls";
private static final String SHEET_NAME = "Test sheet name";
private static final int SHEET_INDEX = 0;
private static final String HEADER = "My header";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(FILE_NAME));
    WritableSheet writableSheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet(SHEET_NAME, SHEET_INDEX);

    int columnIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    writableSheet.addCell(new Label(columnIndex, rowIndex, HEADER));

    for (String value : Arrays.asList("First value", "Second value", "Another value")) {
        writableSheet.addCell(new Label (columnIndex, ++rowIndex, value));
    }

    writableWorkbook.write();
    writableWorkbook.close();
}
```

It created for me an excel file with one sheet. The sheet contains one column with 4 cells: My header, First value, Second value, Another value. Of course, you are free to put there any values you need :)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!